# How to get an elevated powershell in MobaXterm?

Tags: powershell, mobaxterm

Is it possible to create an elevated powershell prompt with MobaXterm? That is, a shell with admin privileges?

Below is a picture of the 'Session' window of MobaXterm with the 'Shell' tab selected, [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmHJj.png). The choice is between Bash, Cmd, Powershell or Ubuntu Bash. However, they open with the permissions of the current user. I'd like to open them (preferably Powershell) as Administrator.

I'm currently using MobaXterm for my ssh needs, and Cmder for local shells. I'd like to harmonize this into a single tool. Cmder has the option to start a new shell as Administrator, but I can not find this option in MobaXterm.

Running Chocolatey is the main thing I'm using an elevated shell for, so it is not *that* annoying to start some other shell for just that once in a while.

[image: mobaxterm shell window]

Comment: Are you asking if you launch a PowerShell command prompt from a MobaXterm terminal or within the terminal have a PowerShell command prompt instance?

Comment: @Ramhound, I've clarified te question to show how I start PowerShell from MobaXterm. I'm not sure to which of your two options this correspond though. My problem is getting this shell elevated so I can enter administrator commands.

Answer (score 7):

This may not be an elegant solution, but this is what worked for me:

- Create a shortcut to MobaXterm: On your desktop (or in some other location, i.e. *Documents*), **right-click > New > Shortcut**
- Browse to the location where MobaXterm is installed, select **MobaXterm.exe**, then click **OK** (i.e. *C:\Program Files (x86)\Mobatek\MobaXterm\MobaXterm.exe*)
- Click **Next**
- Give your shortcut a name, such as **MobaXterm (Admin)**, then click **Finish**
- **Right-click** the shortcut, then click **Properties**
- On the **Shortcut** tab, click the **Advanced...** button
- Select **Run as administrator**, click **OK**, then **OK** again

You'll now be able to run MobaXterm, along with all your sessions with elevated privileges.

**NOTE:** If you want to keep things tidy, you can also move the shortcut to the folder/directory where *MobaXterm.exe* is installed.  If your MobaXterm folder is in one of the **Program Files** folders, you won't be able to create the shortcut directly in that location; however, once your create the shortcut following the above steps, you should be allowed to move the shortcut.

Now if you like, for quick access, you can:

- Pin the shortcut to the taskbar: **Right-click** the shortcut, then click **Pin to taskbar**
- If you use a dock (i.e. *ObjectDock*), you can drag the shortcut to your dock
- Add a shortcut on your Desktop (if you chose to create the shortcut in another location)

Since MobaXterm will now have elevated privileges, you may want to secure it by setting up a **Master Password** (For *MobaXterm Professional only*):

- Launch *MobaXterm Professional*
- Click **Settings > Configuration**
- In the **General** tab, click **MobaXterm passwords management**
- Click the **Set a "Master Password" for strong passwords encryption** button
- Enter a password
- Select **Prompt for master password after resuming from monitor standby mode** to beef up security even more

  - Click **OK**, **OK**, then **OK** again

Comment: I just noticed that when using the above approach, **SFTP/SCP** doesn't work correctly.  You can download files using the SSH-browser pane; however, you won't be able to upload files back to the server. This could be a bug in MobaXterm, but I'm not 100% certain.  If you need SFTP/SCP, then you'll need to use a non-elevated session.

Comment: Thanks, this might indeed work. I'm not really comfortable with running all of MobaXterm as Administrator though. (Even though I can't directly think of an actual attack vector.)

Comment: I can't click the "run as admin" checkbox, it's greyed :/

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't mind that Powershell isn't running in the MobaXterm window you can create a new Session (Shell), choose Powershell and add the following term in *Advanced Shell settings*:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs
```

[image: Session - screenshot]

This is going to open a standalone Powershell session.